# Rviz: Fixed frame [Map] does not exist

Tags: gazebo, rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to do this tutorial [Writing A Global Path Planner As Plugin in ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS) and i finally managed to get to last step, to simulate on Gazebo. After using `roslaunch relaxed_astar test.launch` and `roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch --screen` Gazebo opens but I get an error :

> Fixed frame [Map] does not exist

[image description http://i.hizliresim.com/YJ0bka.png](http://i.hizliresim.com/YJ0bka.png)

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Edit: My map files:

```
image: my_map.pgm
# a 584 X 526 map @ 0.100 m/cell
resolution: 0.1
origin: [-18, -15, 0.0]
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
negate: 0
```

[Map http://i.hizliresim.com/VXp2Av.png](http://i.hizliresim.com/VXp2Av.png)

My launch file :

```
<launch>
<include file="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_bringup/launch/minimal.launch"></include>

  <include file="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_bringup/launch/3dsensor.launch">
    <arg name="rgb_processing" value="false" />
    <arg name="depth_registration" value="false" />
    <arg name="depth_processing" value="false" />
    <arg name="scan_topic" value="/scan" />
  </include>

  <!-- Map server -->
  <arg name="map_file" default="/home/cagurtay/catkin_ws/src/relaxed_astar/maps/my_map.yaml"/>
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />

  <arg name="initial_pose_x" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_y" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_a" default="0.0"/>
  <include file="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/amcl.launch.xml">
    <arg name="initial_pose_x" value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_y" value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_a" value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Move base -->
  <include file="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/move_base.launch.xml"/>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221329/rviz:-fixed-frame-%5Bmap%5D-does-not-exist/) by [Cagurtay](https://answers.ros.org/users/25146/cagurtay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-11-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Have you ever change the Fixed frame?
Maybe you can try this command as below.

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 map my_frame 100
```

Alyson

---

Originally posted by [YingHua](https://answers.ros.org/users/24018/yinghua/) with karma: 196 on 2015-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cagurtay](https://answers.ros.org/users/25146/cagurtay/) on 2015-11-23**:
I don't even know how to change it. I tried your solution, it fixes "Global Status" but there still is RobotModel error: [Screenshot](http://i.hizliresim.com/O922j3.png)

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2017-01-26**:
Hi there! I am getting the exact same error and screenshot you sent. Are you able to solve it?

**Comment by [cmfuhrman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33793/cmfuhrman/) on 2018-03-07**:
I also had this issue and believe the static tf fixed it.